# Differentiate between Cloud directory and Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, azure-active-directory, google-workspace

I was checking **GSuite Directory** and **Azure Directory**. Both the directories provide Active Directory sync using Google Cloud Directory Sync and ADConnect.

With these I can sync my Active Directory with the cloud directory.

Is is possible to differentiate the users/groups/OUs synced from Active Directory from the ones created in cloud itself.

I would like to differentiate in UI as well as using API.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's definitely possible. You can check whether a user's source is "Windows Server AD" or "Azure Active Directory."

Run:

```
Get-AzureADUser -All $true
```

Or:

```
Get-AzureADUser | Where {$_.DirSyncEnabled -ne $true}
```

Comment: Is it possible for GSuite?